# Rendering pixel perfect subtitles for small videos

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I want to burn subtitles with a font as small as possible (yet readable) on top of a small size video, as shown on the first image. FFmpeg makes the font blurry for any font size tried (second image).

```
ffmpeg -i in.jpg -vf "scale=160x128,subtitles=in.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Fontsize=15,Fontname=Silkscreen'" out.png
```

Is there any way I can achieve pixel perfect subtitles with small fonts using FFmpeg or other readily available command line tools? (The smallest font I've found is [Silkscreen](http://kottke.org/plus/type/silkscreen/), though it's ASCII only!)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does [the official `subtitles` video filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) help?

Comment: The rasterization is done by libass, not ffmpeg and AFAICT, antialiasing can't be skipped.

Comment: also note that antialiasing should *not* make things less readable (that's not what it's doing, signal theoretically), unless done wrong

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Antialiasing on very small fonts ruins it. There are no options to bypass this that I can tell.

Comment: @Mulvya: Do you think it would be a feasible feature request?

Comment: Worth a [try](https://github.com/libass/libass/issues), although I don't follow that library's devel. A workaround may be to render the subtitles on large transparent canvas and then downscale it and overlay on the small video.

Comment: That should actually be possible with a clever MUX flow inside ffmpeg

Comment: @Mulvya: I thought about writing a script that renders a PNG for each subtitle, and then apply them to the video with `overlay`, but how do I avoid generating a PNG for every single frame in the video (100K+ frames for a normal film)? My idea so far is to create one PNG per second and use `-r 1`. It will lose some time resolution, but not too much. Is there a better way (that can be done with a separate script, not integrated with the FFmpeg code in any way).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Could you give concrete examples how to do this?

Comment: @forthrin use a script that reads the subtitle file and renders `n` subtitles in advance and concurrently and continuously pipes the current generated image (or an empty transparent frame during pauses) at the desired framerate as a second `rawvideo` input to `ffmpeg` used for the overlay. This is easy to do in `python` with `PIL` for example.

Comment: No need for multiple processes or intermediate files; can be done in a single command. Will write it up in sometime.

Comment: Can you show an output screenshot (and command) using ffmpeg?

Comment: @Mulvya: See update.

Comment: Put the scale at the end.

Comment: Hmm... It looks better, but it's still not pixel perfect. (Why does scaling *after* subtitles give better results? You would have thought scaling ruins the subtitles, if the filters work left to right.)

Comment: Have you tried to make the font bolder? Either by setting Bold=1 in the style override or by explicitly naming a bolder font. It would still be antialiased, but it might look better.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a much better result by enabling font hinting in libass, but it [appears](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) that FFmpeg doesn’t support setting this option currently. Try this with [mpv](https://mpv.io/):

```
mpv in.jpg --vf=scale=160:128 --sub-file=in.srt --sub-ass-hinting=light --sub-font=Silkscreen --sub-font-size=54 --sub-back-color=0/0/0/0.5 --sub-color=1/1/1 --o=out.png
```

(There’s also `--sub-ass-force-style=FontName=Silkscreen,etc.` if you need it or simply prefer to use the ASS syntax directly.)

You may have better luck with `--sub-ass-hinting=normal` or `--sub-ass-hinting=native`, but the value `light` gave me the best result for the image in your question.

Here’s what I got:

[image: Output from mpv using the image from the question.]
[image: Output from mpv using the image from the question and keeping the original source image’s aspect ratio.]

(The source image I found on the Web has a 3:2 aspect ratio, but your example was 4:3. On the left, I had to use `--vf=scale=160:120,dsize=160:120` to match your size and aspect ratio. On the right, I used `--vf=scale=180:120` to match your image height but keep the original aspect ratio.)

For an even better result, you probably need to tweak the font size, as the font in question is optimized for specific sizes as far as I understand. ASS “font size” is not the conventional font size in points (but rather the sum of the ascender and descender heights in pixels), so this isn’t completely trivial, but a bit of experimentation will probably get you there.

Compared to your old approach, this also gives you a cleaner box around/behind the subtitles. When using `BorderStyle=3` with a semitransparent `OutlineColour` like you currently do, there is a separate box for each line of text and those boxes overlap slightly; as a result, you can see a thin area of darker/more intense colour between each two lines of text. This may not be very noticeable at your sizes, but you’ll see it if you look hard enough. As an extension to the ASS format, libass supports a custom `BorderStyle=4`, which produces a single box around the whole text. When setting `--sub-back-color` in mpv, it automatically selects this. (If multiple pieces of text appear simultaneously, each will still have its own box and the boxes may overlap. But based on my very brief search, it seems this situation is rare in SRT files.) Should you want to revert to `BorderStyle=3`, I think you’ll need to add `--sub-ass-force-style=BorderStyle=3` and replace `--sub-back-color` with `--sub-border-color`.